# Login Form (Calling Multiple Sessions) using XML and PHP

Tags: php, xml, session, authentication

Hello ~  I am creating a login form for my Shopping cart assignment , the task is to retrieve the data for each member from xml file and show it on my menu page . So this is my

```
**Login.php** 

    <?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
        $username = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]/', '', $_POST['username']);
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);
        $xml = simplexml_load_file("members.xml");
        $member = $xml->xpath('/members/member[username="'.$username.'"]');

    foreach($member as $memberinfo){ 
    if($memberinfo->username == $username && $memberinfo->password == $password){
    $_SESSION['username']=$username;

    // The coding works perfectly until this point. It wont show the details on menu page if i put these codes .

    $_SESSION['address']=$memberinfo->address;    
    $_SESSION['phonenumber']=$memberinfo->phonenumber; 
    $_SESSION['fullname']=$memberinfo->address;          
    header('Location: Menu.php');
    }
    }
    }
    ?>
```

This is Menu.php page :

```
<?php 
session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){                            
 echo " Hello " .
 $_SESSION['username'] .
 $_SESSION['address'] .
 $_SESSION['phonenumber'] .
 $_SESSION['fullname'] ; }

?>
```

and this is my members.xml

```
**members.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<members>
  <member>
    <username>www</username>
    <fullname>www</fullname>
    <password>4eae35f1b35977a00ebd8086c259d4c9</password>
    <address>www</address>
    <phonenumber>www</phonenumber>
  </member>
  <member>
    <username>we</username>
    <fullname>we</fullname>
    <password>ff1ccf57e98c817df1efcd9fe44a8aeb</password>
    <address>we</address>
    <phonenumber>we</phonenumber>
  </member>
</members>
```

Additional info :  i have tried using Associative array but still didnt show the details .  Please if anyone know the solution would you help me ? Thank you :')

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` does this yield `cannot modify headers: already sent in blah blah blah`

Comment: Does menu.php say 'hello'? Also should the " after $_SESSION['fullname'] be there?

Comment: ahh thank you for pointing that out , ive removed the " .